# Interface between python tty/terminos and a browser terminal emulator

Tags: python, browser, libvirt, terminal-emulator, gateone

There is a python programm named [consolecallback](http://libvirt.org/git/?p=libvirt.git;a=blob;f=examples/python/consolecallback.py) using tty and terminos.

And there are browser terminal emulators like this: [JQueryTerminal](http://terminal.jcubic.pl/) [GateOne](https://github.com/liftoff/GateOne) [ShellInABox](http://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/).

How would I get the consolecallback programm working with one of this terminal emulators in the browser? What is the interface? I have absolutely no idea where to start researching. Please help me by giving some links or anything showing how I can get them to work together. I want to get a libvirt console with all it functions into a browser window. I'm not sure what to google, so please give me some links or better - an explanation...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok I found out myself:

GateOne comes with a server where I can configure "50terminal.conf" file to execute every shell command or script. By telling him to execute consolecallback.py I can open the serial console of a kvm in browser. -> But I don't need this script after all - I can just use normal virsh -c qemu://host/system console vm-name as command in 50terminal.conf and don't need that script at all to get kvm-serial-console into the browser even more simple as by using the python programm...